# How to get the class of Map type

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have to pass the class type of `Map<String, CountryConfig>` in the line `new CouchbaseDAO<>(cbClientProvider, new CountryConfigKeyProvider(), class);` in place of class that is in third argument . But it is not taking it , i have tried like `Map.class` n HashMap.class

```
private static CouchbaseDAO<CountryConfigKey, Map<String, CountryConfig>> getCountryConfigDAO(
            CouchbaseClientProvider cbClientProvider) {
        return new CouchbaseDAO<>(cbClientProvider, new CountryConfigKeyProvider(), Map.class);
    }
```

Couchbase constructor :

```
public CouchbaseDAO(CouchbaseClientProvider couchProvider, CouchbaseKeyProvider<K> keyProvider, Class<T> dataClass) {
        this(OBJECT_MAPPER, couchProvider, keyProvider, dataClass, RetryableCouchbaseTask.NO_RETRIES);
    }
```

Comment: It's not possible. What's `CouchbaseDAO`?

Comment: And what does the `CouchbaseDAO` constructor look like?

Comment: Added the constructor

Comment: If this is for Jackson deserialization, you'll need a `TypeReference`.

Comment: Yes it is for jackson only and I tried it ```private static CouchbaseDAO<CountryConfigKey, Map<String, CountryConfig>> getCountryConfigDAO(
            CouchbaseClientProvider cbClientProvider) {
        return new CouchbaseDAO<>(cbClientProvider, new CountryConfigKeyProvider(),
                new TypeReference<Map<String, CountryConfig>>() { });
    }
``` . but still it is failing

Comment: You could be around long enough to know that you never put more information into comments. You always updater your question instead, especially when there is more code coming.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't use generic types in method/constructor definitions without declaring them at either class level or at method level.

In your `CouchbaseDAO` constructor, you are using generic types `<K>` and `<T>`. In order to do this, you should have declared the class `CouchbaseDAO` with those two types. If you have not done that, then declare it at the constructor like

`public <K, T> CouchbaseDAO(...) {...}`

If you just meant to accept *any* type, then you can skip the generic types and use the *wildcard* character `?` instead.

So, to pass a `Class` type to your constructor, your definition should be `Class<?>` and **NOT** `Class<T>`.

Same goes for `CouchbaseKeyProvider<K>` as well.

Comment: Even if it might be legal grammar (I surprise that it is) I don't think it is a good idea to declare the type-parameters in the constructor and not at the class level; that is a code smell.... what is the point of a that? If the class behavior is not tied to a type (parameter) what is the point of providing one at construction? unless K and T are some how related and this imposes a constraint between several arguments to the constructor, it makes no sense.